# Couchbase View _count Reduce For Given Keys

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase, reduce

I am trying to write a view in Couchbase using a reduce such as _count  which will give me a count of the products at an address.

I have some documents in the database in the following format;

**Document 1**

```
{
    id: 1,
    address: {
        street: 'W Churchill St'
        city: 'Chicago',
        state: 'IL',
    },
    product: 'Cable'
}
```

**Document 2**

```
{
    id: 2,
    address: {
        street: 'W Churchill St'
        city: 'Chicago',
        state: 'IL',
    },
    product: 'Cable'
}
```

**Document 3**

```
{
    id: 3,
    address: {
        street: 'W Churchill St'
        city: 'Chicago',
        state: 'IL',
    },
    product: 'Satellite'
}
```

**Document 4**

```
{
    id: 4,
    address: {
        street: 'E Foster Rd'
        city: 'New York',
        state: 'NY',
    },
    product: 'Free To Air'
}
```

I already have a view which gives me all the products at an address which uses a composite key such as;

```
emit([doc.address.street, doc.address.city, doc.address.state], null)
```

Now this leads me on to the actual problem, I want to be able to get a count of products at a address or addresses.

I want to be able to see for an array of "keys"

```
['W Churchill St','Chicago','IL']
['E Foster Rd','New York','NY']
```

which products and a count of them.  So i would expect to see in my results.

```
'Cable' : 2,
'Satellite': 1,
'Free To Air': 1
```

however if I specified only this "key",

```
['W Churchill St','Chicago','IL']
```

I would expect to see

```
'Cable' : 2,
'Satellite': 1
```

How to write my view to accommodate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this was to append my product to the key like so;

```
emit([doc.address.street, doc.address.city, doc.address.state, doc.product], null)
```

Then using;

```
?start_key=[street,city,state]&end_key=[street,city,state,{}]&group_level=4
```

Result:

```
{"rows":[
    {"key":['W Churchill St','Chicago','IL','Cable'], "value":2},
    {"key":['W Churchill St','Chicago','IL','Satellite'], "value":1}
]}
```

I would then need to repeat this query for each of the addresses and sum the results.